# Docker install dependencies' dependencies

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to launch airflow with docker for a data pipeline project using AWS redshift and s3. After running docker build -t my-airflow . successfully, docker-compose up outputs the error below. It seems like within the docker build process, the dependencies of the dependencies from requirement.txt aren't being installed. In this case, airflow from the requirement.txt is installed although airflow's dependency "typing_extensions" isn't installed.

Output error from running `docker-compose up`:

```
webserver_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 26, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 79, in <module>
webserver_1  |     api_module = import_module(conf.get('cli', 'api_client'))  # type: Any
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
webserver_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/api/client/local_client.py", line 24, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.api.common.experimental import delete_dag
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/delete_dag.py", line 25, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.models.serialized_dag import SerializedDagModel
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/serialized_dag.py", line 32, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.serialization.serialized_objects import SerializedDAG
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/serialization/serialized_objects.py", line 36, in <module>
webserver_1  |     Traceback (most recent call last):
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 26, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 79, in <module>
webserver_1  |     api_module = import_module(conf.get('cli', 'api_client'))  # type: Any
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
webserver_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/api/client/local_client.py", line 24, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.api.common.experimental import delete_dag
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/delete_dag.py", line 25, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.models.serialized_dag import SerializedDagModel
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/serialized_dag.py", line 32, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.serialization.serialized_objects import SerializedDAG
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/serialization/serialized_objects.py", line 36, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.serialization.json_schema import Validator, load_dag_schema
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/serialization/json_schema.py", line 26, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from typing_extensions import Protocol
webserver_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'
webserver_1  | from airflow.serialization.json_schema import Validator, load_dag_schema
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/serialization/json_schema.py", line 26, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from typing_extensions import Protocol
webserver_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/local/airflow/
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY script/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY config/airflow.cfg $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["webserver"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=learning-projects
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Oldmans2ricebowls1tongs4graveyards3
            - POSTGRES_DB=dwh
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        ports:
            - "5439"

    webserver:
        image: my-airflow
        # build:
        #     context: .
        #     args:
        #         AIRFLOW_DEPS: "postgres, aws"
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
        ports:
            - "8080"

        command: webserver
        # healthcheck:
        #     test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
        #     interval: 30s
        #     timeout: 30s
        #     retries: 3
```

**entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TRY_LOOP="20"

# Global defaults and back-compat
: "${AIRFLOW_HOME:="/usr/local/airflow"}"
: "${AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY:=${FERNET_KEY:=$(python -c "from cryptography.fernet import Fernet; FERNET_KEY = Fernet.generate_key().decode(); print(FERNET_KEY)")}}"
: "${AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR:=${EXECUTOR:-Sequential}Executor}"


export \
  AIRFLOW_HOME \
  AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR \
  AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY 

case "$1" in
  webserver)
    airflow initdb
    if [ "$AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR" = "LocalExecutor" ] || [ "$AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR" = "SequentialExecutor" ]; then
      # With the "Local" and "Sequential" executors it should all run in one container.
      airflow scheduler &
    fi
    exec airflow webserver
    ;;
  worker|scheduler)
    # Give the webserver time to run initdb.
    sleep 10
    exec airflow "$@"
    ;;
  flower)
    sleep 10
    exec airflow "$@"
    ;;
  version)
    exec airflow "$@"
    ;;
  *)
    # The command is something like bash, not an airflow subcommand. Just run it in the right environment.
    exec "$@"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Might be missing in airflow's `setup.py`. Just add it manually to your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: how would I go about that? @KlausD.